# PHP | How to send URL in 'content'=>http_build_query?

Tags: php

Im trying to send URL inside the query, But I get an error:

> syntax error, unexpected '=' on line 7

How do I send the URL correctly?

UPDATE 1: now problem in line 8

```
<?php
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"POST",
'content'=>http_build_query("url=http://www.hotstar.com/tv/saath-nibhaana-saathiya/693/meera-humiliates-the-modis/1000055355")
'header'=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0" ,
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" ,
      "Cookie: __cfduid=d1d6556674ee5fe2038c6c516e6ad786f1515596203"
));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "http://en.fetchfile.net/fetch/";
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $data;
```

---

UPDATE 2: 
I do not know why, but the POST request does not receive the JSON

I'm trying to check what the problem is currently, if possible for help thanks

THE WHOLE POST REQUEST:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://en.fetchfile.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hotstar.com%2Ftv%2Fsaath-nibhaana-saathiya%2F693%2Fahemgopi-have-a-fight%2F1000055779
Content-Length: 122
Cookie: __cfduid=d1d6556674ee5fe2038c6c516e6ad786f1515596203; _ym_uid=1515754827599813582; _ym_isad=2; bv_DSKskdck_s1d=bvDSKskdcks1d;  CoinHiveOptOut=1515754855.247; bvppvarnp0=1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Body:

```
url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hotstar.com%2Ftv%2Fsaath-nibhaana-saathiya%2F693%2Fahemgopi-have-a-fight%2F1000055779&action=homePure
```

JSON Response:

```
{"acodec":"mp4a.40.2","description":"Meera humiliates Gopi at the Modi Bhavan. Later, Kinjal gets suspicious seeing Kokila's behaviour. Ahem is furious at Gopi for using his shirt as a cleaning cloth. Gopi reacts to his accusations. Later, Meera hurts Molu's head and humiliates Paridhi for playing a prank on her.","display_id":"1000055779","duration":1296,"episode":"Ahem-Gopi have a fight","episode_number":1369,"ext":"mp4","extractor":"HotStar","extractor_key":"HotStar","format":"hls-4563 - 1920x1080","format_id":"hls-4563","formats":[{"acodec":"mp4a.40.2","ext":"mp4","format":"hls-64 - 250x140","format_id":"hls-64","fps":null,"height":140,"http_headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Charset":"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5","Cookie":"_alid_=Q7nfOk5ehqKpd9pOQBAIiQ==; hdntl=exp=1515843396~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=f1a825da0313c89669ed8f19155bf8410b9f1f6f39068ee04279dd22e7c4e78d","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/47.0 (Chrome)","X-Forwarded-For":"117.200.190.41"},"manifest_url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1515756695~exp=1515757295~acl=/*~hmac=a524380edf50b440821777604ba55f39e4b12b45212be67d878ad7299ec4402f","preference":null,"protocol":"m3u8","tbr":64.0,"url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_1_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgDUL+9aAhYWjMSdWFr0pI0ySbRDIOcQ+v8AA5I0zbQ0kTxVW6Fk8MREQkUs6kKfbBZtynevwukFzQ%3d%3d","vcodec":"avc1.66.30","width":250},{"acodec":"mp4a.40.2","ext":"mp4","format":"hls-121 - 320x180","format_id":"hls-121","fps":null,"height":180,"http_headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Charset":"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5","Cookie":"_alid_=Q7nfOk5ehqKpd9pOQBAIiQ==; hdntl=exp=1515843396~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=f1a825da0313c89669ed8f19155bf8410b9f1f6f39068ee04279dd22e7c4e78d","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/47.0 (Chrome)","X-Forwarded-For":"117.200.190.41"},"manifest_url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1515756695~exp=1515757295~acl=/*~hmac=a524380edf50b440821777604ba55f39e4b12b45212be67d878ad7299ec4402f","preference":null,"protocol":"m3u8","tbr":121.0,"url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_2_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgDUL+9aAhYWjMSdWFr0pI0ySbRDIOcQ+v8AA5I0zbQ0kTxVW6Fk8MREQkUs6kKfbBZtynevwukFzQ%3d%3d","vcodec":"avc1.66.30","width":320},{"acodec":"mp4a.40.2","ext":"mp4","format":"hls-241 - 320x180","format_id":"hls-241","fps":null,"height":180,"http_headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Charset":"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5","Cookie":"_alid_=Q7nfOk5ehqKpd9pOQBAIiQ==; hdntl=exp=1515843396~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=f1a825da0313c89669ed8f19155bf8410b9f1f6f39068ee04279dd22e7c4e78d","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/47.0 (Chrome)","X-Forwarded-For":"117.200.190.41"},"manifest_url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1515756695~exp=1515757295~acl=/*~hmac=a524380edf50b440821777604ba55f39e4b12b45212be67d878ad7299ec4402f","preference":null,"protocol":"m3u8","tbr":241.0,"url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_3_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgDUL+9aAhYWjMSdWFr0pI0ySbRDIOcQ+v8AA5I0zbQ0kTxVW6Fk8MREQkUs6kKfbBZtynevwukFzQ%3d%3d","vcodec":"avc1.66.30","width":320},{"acodec":"mp4a.40.2","ext":"mp4","format":"hls-461 - 416x234","format_id":"hls-461","fps":null,"height":234,"http_headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Charset":"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5","Cookie":"_alid_=Q7nfOk5ehqKpd9pOQBAIiQ==; hdntl=exp=1515843396~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=f1a825da0313c89669ed8f19155bf8410b9f1f6f39068ee04279dd22e7c4e78d","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/47.0 (Chrome)","X-Forwarded-For":"117.200.190.41"},"manifest_url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1515756695~exp=1515757295~acl=/*~hmac=a524380edf50b440821777604ba55f39e4b12b45212be67d878ad7299ec4402f","preference":null,"protocol":"m3u8","tbr":461.0,"url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_4_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgDUL+9aAhYWjMSdWFr0pI0ySbRDIOcQ+v8AA5I0zbQ0kTxVW6Fk8MREQkUs6kKfbBZtynevwukFzQ%3d%3d","vcodec":"avc1.66.30","width":416},{"acodec":"mp4a.40.2","ext":"mp4","format":"hls-861 - 640x360","format_id":"hls-861","fps":null,"height":360,"http_headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Charset":"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5","Cookie":"_alid_=Q7nfOk5ehqKpd9pOQBAIiQ==; hdntl=exp=1515843396~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=f1a825da0313c89669ed8f19155bf8410b9f1f6f39068ee04279dd22e7c4e78d","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/47.0 (Chrome)","X-Forwarded-For":"117.200.190.41"},"manifest_url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1515756695~exp=1515757295~acl=/*~hmac=a524380edf50b440821777604ba55f39e4b12b45212be67d878ad7299ec4402f","preference":null,"protocol":"m3u8","tbr":861.0,"url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_5_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgDUL+9aAhYWjMSdWFr0pI0ySbRDIOcQ+v8AA5I0zbQ0kTxVW6Fk8MREQkUs6kKfbBZtynevwukFzQ%3d%3d","vcodec":"avc1.66.30","width":640},{"acodec":"mp4a.40.2","ext":"mp4","format":"hls-1360 - 720x404","format_id":"hls-1360","fps":null,"height":404,"http_headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Charset":"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5","Cookie":"_alid_=Q7nfOk5ehqKpd9pOQBAIiQ==; hdntl=exp=1515843396~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=f1a825da0313c89669ed8f19155bf8410b9f1f6f39068ee04279dd22e7c4e78d","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/47.0 (Chrome)","X-Forwarded-For":"117.200.190.41"},"manifest_url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1515756695~exp=1515757295~acl=/*~hmac=a524380edf50b440821777604ba55f39e4b12b45212be67d878ad7299ec4402f","preference":null,"protocol":"m3u8","tbr":1360.0,"url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_6_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgDUL+9aAhYWjMSdWFr0pI0ySbRDIOcQ+v8AA5I0zbQ0kTxVW6Fk8MREQkUs6kKfbBZtynevwukFzQ%3d%3d","vcodec":"avc1.66.30","width":720},{"acodec":"mp4a.40.2","ext":"mp4","format":"hls-2062 - 1280x720","format_id":"hls-2062","fps":null,"height":720,"http_headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Charset":"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5","Cookie":"_alid_=Q7nfOk5ehqKpd9pOQBAIiQ==; hdntl=exp=1515843396~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=f1a825da0313c89669ed8f19155bf8410b9f1f6f39068ee04279dd22e7c4e78d","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/47.0 (Chrome)","X-Forwarded-For":"117.200.190.41"},"manifest_url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1515756695~exp=1515757295~acl=/*~hmac=a524380edf50b440821777604ba55f39e4b12b45212be67d878ad7299ec4402f","preference":null,"protocol":"m3u8","tbr":2062.0,"url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_7_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgDUL+9aAhYWjMSdWFr0pI0ySbRDIOcQ+v8AA5I0zbQ0kTxVW6Fk8MREQkUs6kKfbBZtynevwukFzQ%3d%3d","vcodec":"avc1.77.30","width":1280},{"acodec":"mp4a.40.2","ext":"mp4","format":"hls-3062 - 1600x900","format_id":"hls-3062","fps":null,"height":900,"http_headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Charset":"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5","Cookie":"_alid_=Q7nfOk5ehqKpd9pOQBAIiQ==; hdntl=exp=1515843396~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=f1a825da0313c89669ed8f19155bf8410b9f1f6f39068ee04279dd22e7c4e78d","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/47.0 (Chrome)","X-Forwarded-For":"117.200.190.41"},"manifest_url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1515756695~exp=1515757295~acl=/*~hmac=a524380edf50b440821777604ba55f39e4b12b45212be67d878ad7299ec4402f","preference":null,"protocol":"m3u8","tbr":3062.0,"url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_8_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgDUL+9aAhYWjMSdWFr0pI0ySbRDIOcQ+v8AA5I0zbQ0kTxVW6Fk8MREQkUs6kKfbBZtynevwukFzQ%3d%3d","vcodec":"avc1.77.30","width":1600},{"acodec":"mp4a.40.2","ext":"mp4","format":"hls-4563 - 1920x1080","format_id":"hls-4563","fps":null,"height":1080,"http_headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Charset":"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5","Cookie":"_alid_=Q7nfOk5ehqKpd9pOQBAIiQ==; hdntl=exp=1515843396~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=f1a825da0313c89669ed8f19155bf8410b9f1f6f39068ee04279dd22e7c4e78d","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/47.0 (Chrome)","X-Forwarded-For":"117.200.190.41"},"manifest_url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1515756695~exp=1515757295~acl=/*~hmac=a524380edf50b440821777604ba55f39e4b12b45212be67d878ad7299ec4402f","preference":null,"protocol":"m3u8","tbr":4563.0,"url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_9_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgDUL+9aAhYWjMSdWFr0pI0ySbRDIOcQ+v8AA5I0zbQ0kTxVW6Fk8MREQkUs6kKfbBZtynevwukFzQ%3d%3d","vcodec":"avc1.77.30","width":1920}],"fps":null,"height":1080,"http_headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Charset":"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5","Cookie":"_alid_=Q7nfOk5ehqKpd9pOQBAIiQ==; hdntl=exp=1515843396~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=f1a825da0313c89669ed8f19155bf8410b9f1f6f39068ee04279dd22e7c4e78d","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/47.0 (Chrome)","X-Forwarded-For":"117.200.190.41"},"id":"1000055779","manifest_url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1515756695~exp=1515757295~acl=/*~hmac=a524380edf50b440821777604ba55f39e4b12b45212be67d878ad7299ec4402f","playlist":null,"playlist_index":null,"preference":null,"protocol":"m3u8","requested_subtitles":null,"series":"Saath Nibhaana Saathiya","tbr":4563.0,"timestamp":1428499800,"title":"Ahem-Gopi have a fight","upload_date":"20150408","url":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1369/1000055779_,16,54,106,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_9_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgDUL+9aAhYWjMSdWFr0pI0ySbRDIOcQ+v8AA5I0zbQ0kTxVW6Fk8MREQkUs6kKfbBZtynevwukFzQ%3d%3d","vcodec":"avc1.77.30","webpage_url":"http://www.hotstar.com/tv/saath-nibhaana-saathiya/693/ahemgopi-have-a-fight/1000055779","webpage_url_basename":"1000055779","width":1920}
```

Cookies valid until 2019

I send the POST request once again, I get the HTML page of fetchfile, and not the JSON with the video links

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks, it now gives me an error related to the post request, I am trying to arrange if I can not succeed I will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace:

```
http_build_query(url=http://www.hotstar.com/tv/saath-nibhaana-saathiya/693/meera-humiliates-the-modis/1000055355)
```

By

```
http_build_query("url=http://www.hotstar.com/tv/saath-nibhaana-saathiya/693/meera-humiliates-the-modis/1000055355"),
```

Comment: @T.ARKOUT Thank you, and now i get this error: syntax error, unexpected ''header'' line 8. what i need to do?

Comment: You're missing a ","

Comment: You should add "," at the end of line, answer edited

Comment: @T.AKROUT Thanks, it now gives me an error related to the post request, I am trying to arrange if I can not succeed I will update